# Java - AES CBC Algorithum different way to generating SecretKeySpec

Tags: java, encryption, aes, caesar-cipher, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to implement **AES CBC 256** algorithm. And after studying online and checking few code samples I realise that there are two different ways to retrive `SecretKeySpec` and both results in different encrypted message.

```java
    private static SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec(String secretKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        String salt = "a";
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        return new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    }

//    private static SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec(String secretKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
//
//        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
//        digest.update(secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
//        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
//        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
//        return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
//    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = getSecretKeySpec(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivspec);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Would some please let me know which one is the correct implemention of AES CBC 256 bit encryption?

Answer (score 1):

AES & CBC don't specify anything about how you derive the key. Any 128, 192 and 256 bit key are valid. Using an actual key derivation function like PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 is preferable than a single pass to SHA-256 to slow down brute force attack, but otherwise, they both generate valid key.

Comment: If the thing named key is really a key it doesn't need stretching, but it probably can't correctly be handled in a Java `String`. If it's really a _password_, which is quite different, then some PBKDF is needed and for Java (a suitable variant of) PBKDF2 is the easiest good choice.